# Как сделать так, чтобы некоторые файловые системы не обнаруживались в zabbix в delivery rules Mounted filesystem discovery?

Tags: zabbix

У меня на хосте есть папка /var/ftp, которая является корнем для домашних каталогов ftp-пользователей. В эту папку монтируются другие каталоги с помощью команды `mount --bind`. Эта команда создает точки монтирования, которые zabbix тоже считает за файловые системы. Я хочу настроить так, чтобы он их игнорировал.

Я уже самостоятельно пытался найти решение. Я добавил в delivery rules `Mounted filesystem discovery` во вкладке `Filters` такой фильтр (третий в списке под буквой C):
[image: filters]

В этом фильтре указал, что `{#FSNAME}` не должна соответствовать регулярному выражению `^/var/ftp`. Такое регулярное выражение я сделал на основе примера из фильтра по умолчанию `{$VFS.FS.FSNAME.NOT_MATCHES}`, значение которого такое `^(/dev|/sys|/run|/proc|.+/shm$)`.

Интервал времени обнаружения у данного delivery rule является `1h`. Я ждал более часа, но лишние файловые системы `/var/ftp` не пропали, данные для этих систем продолжают обновляться. К тому моменту, как я написал на stackoverflow прошло уже около 3 часов.

Версия zabbix-server 5.0.7.
Версия zabbix-agent 5.0.7.

zabbix-server и zabbix-agent находятся на разных хостах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял, что zabbix не сразу удаляет discovery item'ы, даже если они уже не обнаруживаются.

В списке item'ов они обозначаются специальным предупреждением:
[image: items list]

Их можно удалить вручную и они больше не появятся.

Это значит, что решение работает, которое я описал в вопросе, хоть и не сразу.